# Android - Animation Not smooth having Intermediate Screen

Tags: android, animation

I have a requirement to have an intermediate activity as an deciding authority to navigate which doesn't have any layout to inflate and it is not finished even after the target activity is started.

**IntermediateActivity**

```
if(condition1){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   // not finished
}
else{
 .......
}
```

Here in Intermediate Activity, 
If we `finish()` it after starting the Target Activity, `the Animation is very smooth` as normal.
But if we `didn't finish()` the intermediate activity, `the animation is coming but it is not smooth. There is blink in between.`

```
I want to understand
```

If we finish an activity, how it is smooth . will it take previous activity for animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally as an work around , I have set backgroundDrawable as `Transparent` in onCreate() of that intermediate Activity.

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```